# How to set multiple values within only one iteration in pandas table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am iterating over a pandas table using the itertuples() iterator function. I would like to set a value in another column when a condition is True. Thats easy. But I would like to set another value based on the previously set value to another column again and thats not working. I have to iterrate a second time to do that, but this is inefficient. 
How can i set multiple values in different columns within one iteration process.

Here is some example code:

```
data = {
'Animal': ['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'dog', 'cow'],
'Noise': ['muh', 'miau', 'wuff', 'piep', 'piep', 'miau', 'muh']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.insert(loc=2, column='Match', value='')
df.insert(loc=3, column='Comment', value='')
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.Animal == 'cat' and row.Noise == 'miau':
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)
    elif row.Animal == 'dog' and row.Noise == 'wuff':
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)
    elif row.Animal == 'bird' and row.Noise == 'piep':
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)
    elif row.Animal == 'cow' and row.Noise == 'muh':
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)

    # Why is this not getting applied to the 'Comment' column?
    if row.Match is True:
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Comment', value='yeah')
```

I have to do another iteration instead to get the Comment-column filled:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.Match is True:
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Comment', value='yeah')
```

But with i.e. 500000+ values this is very inefficient and time consuming.
So what is a better way to do something like that?

Comment: Why not do it in the same loop? It looks like you're always setting them at the same time

Comment: Also, consider using a single conditional and using `or`. That way, you don't need to keep repeating code

Comment: Because it is not working in the same loop. This is exactly the question why it is not possible in the same loop. ;-)

Comment: I meant you can do `df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)
 df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Comment', value='yeah')`. But the below is a much better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your `df`

```
data = {
'Animal': ['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'dog', 'cow'],
'Noise': ['muh', 'miau', 'wuff', 'piep', 'piep', 'miau', 'muh']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'd use an initially calculated dictionary defining what a match is.  Then, use `map` to convert and test for equality.  After that, I'd use `assign` to produce the desired columns.

```
matches = dict(cat='miau', dog='wuff', bird='piep', cow='muh')

match = df.Animal.map(matches) == df.Noise

df.assign(Match=match, Comment=np.where(match, 'yeah', ''))

  Animal Noise  Match Comment
0    cat   muh  False        
1    dog  miau  False        
2    dog  wuff   True    yeah
3    cat  piep  False        
4   bird  piep   True    yeah
5    dog  miau  False        
6    cow   muh   True    yeah
```

---

To answer your specific question:
Your `row` within the loop is no longer attached to the dataframe.  So when you make the assignment of `True` or `False` to the dataframe with `set_value`, you won't be able to access that value you just set from `row`.  Instead, use `df.get_value`

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.Animal == 'cat' and row.Noise == 'miau':
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)
    elif row.Animal == 'dog' and row.Noise == 'wuff':
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)
    elif row.Animal == 'bird' and row.Noise == 'piep':
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)
    elif row.Animal == 'cow' and row.Noise == 'muh':
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Match', value=True)

    # This should work
    if df.get_value(index=row.Index, col='Match') is True:
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Comment', value='yeah')
```

Comment: This is definitely a more elegant way to populate the "Match"- and the 'Comment' - Column for this specific example as I did. Never heard of 'map' and 'assign'. Thanks for that idea. Anyway, the focus of the question is how to populated multiple columns/cells within one loop.

Comment: Imagine that the 'Match'-Column is calculated from some other Columns in a more complicated way. I calculate the True/False result within an itertuples loop and based an the result i would like to populate another cell and based on that again another cell in another column. But I don´t want to iterate again for every result. Instead it would be nice to do all the cascading calculations within one loop.

Comment: Yes, df.get_value() was the missing part for that specific question, thanks!

Comment: Anyway, are 'assign' and 'map' iterating internally too? So in your first solution for this specific example the table is getting looped twice, right?

Comment: @qfactor they are vectorized assignments.  I wouldn't call anything in my proposed solution a "loop".  Actually, my apologies.  The map is a loop but an optimized one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 # Why is this not getting applied to the 'Comment' column?
    if row.Match is True:
        df.set_value(index=row.Index, col='Comment', value='yeah')
```

you can use this after the for loop.

```
df['Comment'] = df['Match'].apply(lambda x: 'yeah' if x == True else '')
```